# Does absolute retract imply convex structure?

Tags: gn.general-topology, convex-polytopes, convexity

In the [theory of selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_selection_theorem), it is known that any compact absolute retract (AR) carries a convexity structure defined by [E. Michael](https://web.archive.org/web/20201211234809id_/https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/94588000B6D58A566AE36AB90EA87CC3/S0008414X00003424a.pdf/div-class-title-convex-structures-and-continuous-selections-div.pdf). It is also known that a convex structure
developed by [Van de Vel](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1993-336-02/S0002-9947-1993-1169083-9/S0002-9947-1993-1169083-9.pdf) requires a space which is both globally and locally an AR. Therefore, AR alone does not guarantee the convexity in the manner of Van de Vel. But what if we allow the space to be locally AR? More specifically, my question is

> **Question**
> Does a metric space which is both globally and locally an AR have **S**$_4$ convex structure with
> compact polytopes and with connected convex sets?

The motivation is seeking a (partial) converse of the following theorem of Van de Vel.

**Theorem** Let $X$ be metrizable space which have **S**$_4$ convex structure with compact polytopes and with connected convex sets. Then each nonempty convex set in $X$ is an AR.

Here are some definition just for the convenience of the readers.
The axiomatic convex structure defined by Van de Vel is: A family $\mathcal{C}$ of subsets of a set $Y$ is called a *convexity* on $Y$ if:
[image]
[image]

The convex structure in the manner of Michael can be formalized as:
[image]